# $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{W(n)}{\sqrt{n}}>c)\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\mathbb{P}(W(n)/\sqrt{n}>c)>0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $W(t)$ be a Wienerprocess, why does the following inequality hold,

$$\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{W(n)}{\sqrt{n}}>c)\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\mathbb{P}(W(n)/\sqrt{n}>c)$$

Comment: Always $\mathbb P(\limsup_n A_n) \ge \limsup_n \mathbb P(A_n)$. It's just "dual" version of Fatou Lemma, which states that if $(f_n)_n$ are non-negative and (uniformly) bounded from above, then $\int \limsup_n f_n \ge \limsup_n \int f_n$.  Since $\mathbb P(A_n) = \mathbb E[1_{A_n}]$, the result follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the Fatou's lemma idea suggested by @Dominik more detailed, we notice that by continuity of probability $$\mathbb{P}(\limsup A_n)=\mathbb{P}(\cap_{n\geq 1}\cup_{m\geq n}A_m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\cup_{m\geq n}A_m),$$

while $$\mathbb{P}(\cup_{m\geq n}A_m)\geq\mathbb{P}(A_m),$$

for any $m\geq n$, wihch yields $$\mathbb{P}(\cup_{m\geq n}A_m)\geq\sup_{m\geq n}\mathbb{P}(A_m).$$

By taking limits on both sides we get the formula you want.